# Is it possiable to change gridview pagination button count globally in yii2?

Tags: pagination, yii2, page-size

this is working perfect. but, I want to globalize this pager setting

```
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'pager' => [
        'maxButtonCount' => 5,
        'options' => [
            'tag' => 'ul',
            'class' => 'pagination pagination-sm',
        ]
    ],
    'columns' => .....   
]);
```

my code is this in component section. But, It is not working.

```
'components' => [
    .....

    'pager' => [
        'class' => yii\widgets\LinkPager::class,
        'maxButtonCount' => 5,
        'options' => [
            'tag' => 'ul',
            'class' => 'pagination pagination-sm',
        ]
    ],
],
```

Comment: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-di-container#practical-usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to handle pagination button count globally

```
$config = [
    ....
    'container' => [
        'definitions' => [
            'yii\widgets\LinkPager' => [
                'maxButtonCount' => 6,
                'options' => [
                    'tag' => 'ul',
                    'class' => 'pagination', //pagination-sm
                ]
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'components' => [
        ...
    ],
];
```

Comment: Alright, seems good, why not accepting your own answer :) ?

Comment: Accept button enable after 48 hr of posting post. Now I accepted.